# Locate view fails when using areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an area in my project but the view engine fails to find my view, it does not look for views in my areas directory?

The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/foo/Index.aspx
~/Views/foo/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/foo/Index.cshtml
~/Views/foo/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the area you want to use when creating ActionLinks and if you're registering routes outside of the area.

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Test", "Action", "Controller", new { area = "MyArea" }, null) %>
```